# Distributed Winforms application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, wcf, tcp

I am looking to change the current architecture of distributed winforms application developed using TCP messages and the client talks to database directly. I know this a bad design and I am entrusted to change this. I have been recruited for the same.

Bit of Overview:

1. Client uses Winforms applications
2. Client loads the initial data from database directly
3. Clients listens to the Server (Winforms application with TCP listener)
4. If an update is made in an any of the entity, client will update the database directly and sends the message to server, which in turn send the information to other clients. Then these clients would refresh the data from database

Technologies Used: VB.NET, Entity framework, Oracle Database and TCP Listener.

I need all your advise about what would be best solution/architecture for the same. I thinking about using WCF with duplex communications for messages.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `WinForms` (or `WPF` if you can) client, `WCF` server, `EntityFramework` for `ORM` and `Oracle` for `DB`. 
The client calls the server. the server uses `EF` to call the `DB`. This 3 tier design is pretty common and basic. What's wrong with it?

PS: I would recommend against using duplex communication because it's over complicated and doesn't always work. What is your specific need for it?

Comment: +1 for mentioning WPF. It's **way** easier and better for data-centric applications than winforms.

Comment: How can I push the changes made in one client to another client immediately?

Comment: The common way is to have a refresh cycle the polls the server.  For quicker notification look at WebSockets or SignalR